# Do I need to remove all carpet adhesive residue before using a floor leveler?

Tags: concrete, floor, slab, primer, leveling

We have a slab foundation on our place. The previous owners put down carpet with pad and there's a fair amount of glue and pad residue on the concrete, as well as some paint overspray. We'll need to level the floor and roll on a liquid moisture barrier before putting down flooring. Two questions:

Do I need to grind off every bit of glue and stuff before putting on concrete leveler primer?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to DIY. Did the post not first read vinyl plank? What flooring are you thinking?

Comment: Product recommendation requests are off topic here. I've removed that portion of your post.

Comment: Welcome, and please take the [tour].

Comment: @isherwood I took the original question to mean what type of primer etc... not necessarily which brand. I'd be ok with questions of what type.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought discussion of _types_ of primer to be useful. How many categories can there be? It's a matter of reading labels to find one that fits the need. Feel free to edit further if you disagree. I'm easy.

Comment: @isherwood, agree, question is fine as edited. I wanted at least to mention that priming as a separate step depends on the cement. As you write too, read the label.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know...was more interested in type of coating than specific brand.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a floating vinyl floor (as originally posted), you need to scrape away the high spots, lay down an underlayment that has vapour barrier with foam and optionally felt to provide a smoothing cushion.

For planks, there's no need to prime or scrape bare.

As for flatness and smoothness, the manufacturer will specify it, but usually anything less than 1/16in is not a problem, and some bowing and bending over several multiples of the plank length or its width is tolerated quite well.

If you are flattening with self-leveling cement, for whatever reason, you have to scrape the concrete bare, entirely.

As for a concrete or cement primer, read the label on the self-leveling cement: some don't need primer and they are more expensive. Others require primer which you can add-in or roll-on to your surface.

Which one you choose depends a bit on how thick the layer will be: anything over 1/4 (very roughly) and it's more economical to roll it on first, otherwise you're just mixing very expensive cement.